# Sound not working in Java

Tags: java, audio

I've been researching sound files in Java for the past couple of days and I thought I finally could try and get some sound running.

I coded a small segment but unfortunately, there is no sound be played after running it.
Is there a bug somewhere that I'm not seeing or does this code not work. Thanks.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class driver {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) throws Exception {
        URL resourceUrl = new URL("file:;///C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/Pok/pokemon.wav");
        final AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(resourceUrl);
        clip.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem it's in your url. Try to remove `file:;///` but I'm not secure about that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with...

```
URL resourceUrl = new URL("file:;///C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/Pok/pokemon.wav");
```

Apart from the fact that there is a `;` in the path which doesn't belong, there is a simpler way to generate a `URL` from a `File`

```
URL url = new File("C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/Pok/pokemon.wav").toURI().toURL();
```

Then move onto this...

```
final AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(resourceUrl);
```

Looking at your code, you program isn't an applet, so you really shouldn't be using `Applet` based methods.

For better ways, start by taking a look at [Sound Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)

Which might look something more like...

```
URL url = new File("C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/Pok/pokemon.wav").toURI().toURL();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
clip.start();
clip.drain(); // Stop the main thread from exiting
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C:\\Users\\Jack\\Desktop\\Pok\\pokemon.wav` on Windows?

Comment: @immibis On windows, it won't make a difference.  Only on *nix systems does the path separates make a difference.  Been using this for 15+ years ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer what imports do i need for your example code?

Comment: @johnnguyen You will most likely need `javax.sound.sampled.*` as a start

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method to Open an audio clip:

> ```
> public SoundClipTest() {
>       try {
>          URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("pokemon.wav");
>          AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
>          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
>          clip.open(audioIn);
>          clip.start();
>       } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think there's something wrong with your url, but not sure. However you could try this to play a sound:

```
String mySound = "pokemon.wav";
Media media = new Media(mySound);
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
mp.play();
```

You should have pokemon.wav in the same folder where your java file is.